# RGeo: error when running spatial migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I'm working with Rails 3.2 and MySQL.
I installed the gems:

```
gem 'rgeo', '0.3.20'  
gem 'rgeo-activerecord', '0.4.6'
gem 'activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter', '0.4.3'
```

all other requirements and dependencies are met, or at least I think so.
Yet, following the suggested procedure for creating a model with spatial data in it ([here](http://dazuma.github.io/activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter/rdoc/)), step-by-step, when I run this migration:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.point :latlon
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error:

undefined method 'point' for #/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rgeo-activerecord-0.4.6/lib/rgeo/active_record/common_adapter_elements.rb:105:in 'method_missing'

Anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
t.point :latlon
```

to

```
t.column :latlon, :point, :null => false
```

Comment: you this fixes it, but why is it necessary. i thought that t.point was supported by the plugin.